# Polygons from different layers

Tags: polygon, layers, merge, arcgis-pro, overlay

[image: polygons from all the different layers]

How to create a map with polygons from all the different layers?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro and it does not have Overlay analysis tool.

Comment: Use union tool to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [merge tool] (http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/merge.htm)

[image]

> Combines multiple input datasets into a single, new output dataset. This tool can combine point, line, or polygon feature classes or tables.
>
> Use the Append tool to combine input datasets with an existing dataset.
>
> Use this tool to combine datasets from multiple sources into a new, single output dataset. All input feature classes must be of the same geometry type. For example, several point feature classes can be merged, but a line feature class cannot be merged with a polygon feature class.
>
> Tables and feature classes can be combined in a single output dataset. The output type is determined by the first input; if the first input is a feature class, the output will be a feature class, if the first input is a table, the output will be a table. If a table is merged into a feature class, the rows from the input table will have null geometry.
>
> All fields in the output dataset and the contents of those fields can be controlled using the Field map.
>
> This tool will not split or alter the geometries from the input datasets. All features from the input datasets will remain intact in the output dataset, even if the features overlap. To combine, or planarize, feature geometries, use the Union tool.
>
> If feature classes are being merged, the output dataset will be in the coordinate system of the first feature class in the Input Datasets list, unless the Output Coordinate System geoprocessing environment is set.
>
> This tool does not support annotation feature classes.
>
> This tool does not support raster datasets. Use the Mosaic To New Raster tool to merge multiple rasters into a new output raster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the merge tool:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/editing/merge-features-into-one-feature.htm

Or you can use the append tool:
http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/append.htm

Note: You will need to make sure the schema of all the feature classes is the same. If not then carefully map the fields.